# JTree from List<File>

Tags: java, list, jtree, file-manager

I need a way to create a JTree from a list of Files. How could I create the Nodes, which classes and methods should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here is the code**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTree.htm)
[another one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/FileTreeDemo.htm)